# Trouble understanding how to use findNextSiblings

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have some html that I am parsing with BeautifulSoup ...

```
<div class="book-page-sidebar">
    <h4>Production details</h4>
    <dl class="product-details clearfix">
      <dt>Running Time:</dt>
      <dd>1:20:25</dd>

      <dt>Zip file size:</dt>
      <dd>38.6MB</dd>

      <dt>Catalog date:</dt>
      <dd>2010-05-04</dd>

      <dt>Read by:</dt>
      <dd><a href="https://librivox.org/reader/204">Mark F. Smith</a></dd> 

      <dt>Book Coordinator:</dt>
      <dd><a href="https://librivox.org/reader/204">Mark F. Smith</a></dd>

      <dt>Meta Coordinator:</dt>
      <dd><a href="https://librivox.org/reader/4009">Diana Majlinger</a></dd>

      <dt>Proof Listener:</dt>
      <dd><a href="https://librivox.org/reader/496">Ans Wink</a></dd>                 
    </dl>

</div>
```

I want to grab the text `1:20:25` in the dd tag after dt tag with the text `Running Time:`.
So I tried this bit of code ...

```
paraText = soup.find( text = re.compile ('Running Time:') )
print paraText.findNextSiblings('dd')
```

... but there is no output.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find_next or findNext should do the trick.

```
paraText = soup.find( text = re.compile ('Running Time:') )
print paraText.findNext('dd')
```

Comment: awesome! thanks you just saved me hours of banging my head against the wall :)

Comment: Np, you should checkout all the methods the beautiful soup lib has to provide. Quick hacky method is to simply print dir(soup). Cheers.